# Deleting falsy values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, boolean

I'm studying at freeCodeCamp, and currently learning basic algorithms. I'm doing the falsy bouncer exercise at which you need to remove all falsy values from the array. Sadly there was only the advanced answer for the task, that uses the filter() method. I've decided to make a basic one, but currently stuck.

```
function bouncer(arr) { 

//*loops through array*    

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  

// *if there is a value that is falsy, delete that value from the array*    

if (arr[i] == 0 || arr[i] == NaN || arr[i] == null || arr[i] == false || arr[i] == "" || arr[i] == undefined) {        

delete arr[i];

     }    

   }    

return arr;

} 

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

It returns:

> 7,ate,,,9.

The function, indeed removed the falsy values, but I'm left with those three periods(,,,). Is there a way to make this function to work more correct and to return truthy values without those periods, without losing the simplicity of the function?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: `arr[i] == NaN` is never `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to Javascript and you need your code to work other than a different solution, you can do this

remove `delete arr[i];` and replace it with `arr.splice(i,1); i--;`

This will remove the item in `i`th position and 1 means 1 item from `i`th position.
Since the element in `i`th position is removed and a new element is in there. We need to continue again from there. So we need to add `i--`. Otherwise in the next iteration it will start from the next element instead of `i`th position.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0 || Number.isNaN(arr[i]) || arr[i] == null || arr[i] == false || arr[i] == "" || arr[i] == undefined) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, NaN, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wanted to use splice, but it seems I lacked the i--, which gave me really wrong answer.

Comment: One more question, what should I do with NaN property? When I insert as a parameter [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""], it returns NaN, when it should return [].

Comment: @MarkSheleg You can use `Number.isNaN(arr[i])` instead of `arr[i] == NaN` for that purpose. I have updated the code with that.

Answer (score 5):

`delete` only works on objects. `filter` will do what you want:

```
const arr = [7, "ate", "", false, 9]

console.log(arr.filter(x => x))
```

`filter` retains only those elements in the array for which the function returns true - here I use `x => x` because you only want truthy elements

Comment: `Boolean` can be used instead of `x => x`.

Comment: @Xufox yes, it can - is there an advantage?

Comment: No need for new variable `x`, no need to create a new function.

Comment: I think this is a clever solution.

Answer (score 3):

This will do

```
var m = arr.filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Delete` works only on `Object`.

**Simply you can do it like this since you're wiling to use simple for loop**

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
let op =[];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i]){
    op.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
return op;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Comment: why would you want to do this instead of using `.filter`?

Comment: @ic3b3rg ` Sadly there was only the advanced answer for the task, that uses the filter() method. I've decided to make a basic one, but currently stuck` he want to understand alternate and i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Used `map` method and `Boolean()` for comparison.

```
const bouncer = arr => {

    let newArr = [];

    arr.map(e => {
        if (Boolean(e) == true) {
            newArr.push(e)
        }
    });


    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.